# how to link local IP Address to a domain name in local network, so website can be accessible to any device using the domain name?

Tags: node.js, express, dns, network-programming, subdomain

I am a **NOOB** to programming and networking so please forgive me for any mistakes.

I have searched on **stack,google** for my problem but the solutions
i found didn't went well with me and so **please** do consider answering my question
even if you consider it is simple or duplicate question.

**My Problem** - I have a `nodeJS` server built using *express* and it can be accessed on
address `http://192.168.209.239:8001/` now i want to access server using domain names like normal website say i want to access the server using `http://myserver.app/`

**found Solutions** - i found about `DNS` but i was not able to set it up, then i found that editing the `etc/host` file can solve this but domain name was only working on my laptop where the app is running, if i connect my **phone** to **same network*** and when i type the domain name it does **not** work.

I found about `mDNS`. but i was a very old post which told we can use **Apple Bonjour** but it is not working as i learned that Microsoft has done some implementation of `mDNS`
so make Bonjour work disable mDNS in registry and i am not willing to do that.

**What i ask** - please give me step by step guide how to stepup DNS or mDNS on my machine
so if any device connects to my network it can access the NodeJS app thought its browser using domain URL `http://myserver.app/`

**I am using**
`nodeJS@16.13.2`,
`express@4.17.2`,
`Windows 11 version 21H2 build 22000.376`

My Network is like I have connected my mobile hotspot to laptop
and any new device to connected to hotspot so may my mobile is kind of a wifi router.

if a different laptop connects to my hotspot i should be able to access the website using the domain name. `myserver.app`

My Phone is using `Android 11`
and please do consider
I do not want to use any online DNS providers like easyDns or AWS
i want a local solution which i can run on my laptop

Comment: "http://myserver.app/" You can't do that. `app` is a Google TLD, and it was added to the HSTS Preloading list. Said differently, you need to use https and hence you need to have a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ideally you need to DNS server for this : but its wont work with dynamic IP as your machine ip can change after reboot
2. You can add domain as host entry on each machine : this will not work with mobile and also need to change ip as your machine / server ip change
3. If you have static ip , just go for any dns service provider easydns , aws and as its inetrnall ip will work for all devices which are in network
4. Found This may work for y https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/how-to-configure-ddns-in-router/

Comment: Sir thank you for the help But the Post you gave is about DDNS on a wifi router and i do not have a router i use my phone hotspot and my phone hotspot does not have any DDNS settings and i do not want to access my app via global internet and i just want o access it on my local network without any use of online DNS providers like AWS.

Comment: try bind then https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android 9 Pie it is possible to change DNS globally, provided they support TLS. Just go in

Settings → Network & internet → Advanced → Private DNS

Comment: Sir thank you for the suggestion i found the setting but as i mentioned in my post that i an a new to these things so could you tell me how to setup a `DNS` server locally which points to my website?